# silverlight listbox stackpanel items define background color by templated item value

Tags: c#, silverlight, listbox, datatemplate

I want to chang background color the border or stackpanel by binded item's value

```
 <controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
        <l:StringToColorConverter x:Key="converter"/>
    </controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
...
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">

                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" Background="{Binding Cím, Converter={StaticResource converter}}"  x:Name="hatter" BorderThickness="4" CornerRadius="20">
                            <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource dolgozostack}"
                                         Margin="2,2,2,2">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Cím}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Foreground="White" FontSize="13" TextAlignment="Center" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
```

And here is my converter:

```
    public class StringToColorConverter:IValueConverter
        {
            public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
           object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
            {
                if (value.ToString().ToLower() == "Megvalósítás elindítva".ToLower())
                    return Colors.Green;
                else{
                     SolidColorBrush mybrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
                return mybrush;
}

            }
    }
```

Find its working with SolidColorBrush

Comment: Ah find it have to define {SolidColorBrush mybrush=new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by binding `Background` property that you want to change to item's value, and use Converter that will return specific color brush given specific value.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Full_Name}" FontSize="16" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"
        Foreground="{Binding Full_Name, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}" />
```

For Reference :

- WPFTutorial.net : [Value Converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html)
- MSDN : [IValueConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- MSDN : [WPF Brushes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970904%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)